# Select from Array of Hashes only elements included in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays:

```
arr = ["test", "hello", "year"]

arr_hashes = [{"value": "yes", "key":"test"},{"value": "no", "key":"hello"},{"value": "noway", "key":"yessir"},{"value": "never", "key":"year"}]
```

I want to return:

```
new_arr = [{"value": "yes", "key":"test"},{"value": "no", "key":"hello"},{"value": "never", "key":"year"}]
```

What I have no which is not filtering at all:

```
arr_hashes.select {|x| x['key'].include?(arr)}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply the other way around `arr.include?(x['key'])`

so

```
arr_hashes.select { |x| arr.include?(x['key']) }
```

the object which receives the message, `include?`, is an array, and the parameter is the element you want to know whether it's included or not in the array

Comment: This is still returning the original array value. How can I actually return the new set of hashes?

Comment: This returns the items for which the condition in the select is true. If you got the same array this condition is not working